# How to convert a Git log date format to an integer?

Tags: python, git, gitpython

I want store a date from git log to compare them then, but when I'm storing them into an array, It says they are string type and I don't know how to convert this such format (e.q  `commited date: Mon Aug 22 15:43:38 2016 +0200`).

```
date = commits[i]['Date']  
print("commited date:", date) 
moduleDate.append(date)
upToDateModule = max(moduleDate) #trigger here

Traceback (most recent call last):   File
"/home/savoiui/PycharmProjects/VersionChecker/versionCheckerV4.py",
line 120, in <module>
    main()   File "/home/savoiui/PycharmProjects/VersionChecker/versionCheckerV4.py",
line 110, in main
    upToDateModule = max(moduleDate)
 TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)
```

Comment: Could you give us a full traceback of an error?

Comment: witch of the three lines of code does trigger the error ?

Comment: It would be more convenient to get the date as a Unix epoch timestamp if you want to compare two dates. To get the commit date of a commit for example, `git log $commit -1 --pretty=%cd --date=unix`. There should be gitpython methods that can get the same result.

Comment: I've added the full traceback and added the triggered line

Comment: what is the `+0200` in the end of your date ? the number of the new lines in the commit ?

Comment: I don't know it's in every  commits  logs even shown by the console:
commit 4a5d9edbfvr54btgb4564215eaceee21201d3afaf

Author: an author

Date:   Thu Nov 30 12:13:13 2017 +0100

    [FIX] ##12465

Comment: sure it's not significant for the needed date

Comment: @MJanaTiI That is a time zone offset. Similar to what's described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_offsets_from_UTC) for the ISO 8601 time format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try converting your date string to datetime format before appending them to the `moduleDate` list like

```
from datetime import datetime

date = commits[i]['Date']
print("commited date:", date) 
# commited date: Mon Aug 22 15:43:38 2016 +0200

datetime_object = datetime.strptime(' '.join(date.split(' ')[:-1]), '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y') 

moduleDate.append(datetime_object) 
upToDateModule = max(moduleDate)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Can you please mark it as resolved https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111630/how-to-mark-a-question-on-so-as-resolved

Comment: I've done that, but  I have tried it on another project  and  I have this error:
ValueError: time data 'Thu Jan 14 12:47:30 2016' does not match format '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y'
can you help me please?

Comment: Just tested the string you gave with the previous format and it works, here is how to construct the format to suit the date you have https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior

Comment: Are you sure this `Thu Jan 14 12:47:30 2016` is the string causing the error ? cuz it suites the format provided earlier perfectly, it works for me, can you provide more details please ?

Comment: When I try to convert the received date into a valid dateTime format, their format never match:
print(receivedDate) #got Thu Jan 14 12:47:30 2016 +0100 and then
date = datetime.strptime(receivedDate, '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y %z').strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')   #got ValueError: time data 'Thu Jan 14 12:47:30 2016 +0100' does not match format '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y %z',
with the debugger I found this is because of the month name and the day of the week name, but I have no idea how to fix that (I tested with locale.setlocale, however it works in french language but I dont want like this)

Comment: Well I think it's because you didn't remove the `+0100` from the end of the date string, try `receivedDate=' '.join(receivedDate.split(' ')[:-1])`  before converting your string to datetime

Comment: I've also tried it and got:
ValueError: time data 'Thu Jan 14 12:47:30 2016' does not match format '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y %z' (the %z becomes optionnal now)

Comment: Please contact me on my twitter or github account, to continue debugging the problem

Comment: I will add you asap if you're still interested to resolve this problem

Comment: If you want to include the timezone use: `datetime.strptime(' '.join(time.split(' ')), '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y %z')`

Answer (score 0):

To get a datetime from a string, you could use the [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) library, with the `strptime()` method.

> NB: Did you use `//` to comment? In python, you comment with the `#` character

Comment: Ok I'll try :)
The double slashs are just for comments in stackOverflow, I'm just used to comment this way from java, I've changed it